# No matching configuration of project :react-native-phonepe-pg was found

Tags: android, react-native, payment-gateway, phonepe

getting error in react native

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-phonepe-pg.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :react-native-phonepe-pg was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

"react-native": "0.64.4

allprojects {

```
repositories {
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url  "https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-intentsdk-android"
    }
}
```